# how can i create a button like the ones in the picture

Tags: html, css

The button in the picture is a default button with curved corner. I create a default button and tried to use border-radius to change radius of the corners, but it also changed the button appearance like background colour.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDi56.png)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Might browse the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) area and see how maybe make the question more clear with provided attempts of what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: These are the default style of buttons. unless you specified button css somewhere in your style sheet

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below
Css:

```
button.myButton{
    padding: 8px 17px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #808080;
    color: black;
    font-size: 19px;
}
```